# Is the context for the Apache2 Options command varying depending on the flags used?

Tags: apache2, administration

As I was testing various things to make sure my Apache installation was as secure as possible, I decided check whether I would see a directory list of files. So I created a test directory and added a couple of files:

```
/var/www/domain/public_html/test
/var/www/domain/public_html/test/a.txt
/var/www/domain/public_html/test/b.txt
```

To my surprise, when I went to that test directory, I saw `a.txt` and `b.txt` listed.

I went back to my setup file and I did have the `Options -Indexes` setup, so I was wondering why I would see the files `a.txt` and `b.txt`

Only my setup looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost domain:80>
  ...
  Options -Indexes
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Looking at the [documentation for the Options command](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options), it clearly says:

```
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

Yet, when I put that specific option directly at the `VirtualHost` level, it does not do anything.

I changed the setup to move the `Options` in a `Directory` tag and it works.

```
<VirtualHost domain:80>
  ...
  <Directory "/var/www/domain/public_html/">
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Is that just a big Gotcha!? Something that one needs to know about to avoid NOT turning off the option one wants to turn off???

Comment: Do you have mod_autoindex enabled? In /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ do you see autoindex.conf and autoindex.load? If so, how about dir.conf and dir.load? I remember having to enable some module to make the `-Index` work on my test server, however, I do not remember which one. Both of these effect directory indexes. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc, note that I was trying (and succeeded) in turning it off. So in that respect, I'm good. I also now fully removed the `autoindex` because my point of view is that it should not be there unless you really want it. What I'm super surprise about, though, is the fact that the Options did not work until I added it inside the `<Directory>` tag...

Comment: Huh! Interesting. I am glad you got it. It was last year I hit a similar problem, however, I cannot remember exactly what all I had to do. I know that I had to enable a module. I just don't remember the details. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Options -Indexes` directly in the VirtualHost container. However, whether it will have the desired effect when defined here or not will depend on whether `Options` have been defined anywhere else in the server config. For instance, any `<Directory>` sections defined *anywhere* else (that relate to the directory being accessed) are likely to override this, since they are processed later in the request.

`Options` defined directly in the VirtualHost container will only override `Options` defined directly in the server config.

Since the `Options` directive "controls which server features are available in a particular directory", it is far more common to see this in `<Directory>` containers. Defining `Options` directly in the server config / VirtualHost is only suitable for defining a *base default*. However, it is common to see defaults set in a `<Directory />` container in the server config which will control the entire server - an `Options` directive here would override any `Options` declared directly in the VirtualHost. (Note that "server defaults" should not be declared with the `+`/`-` prefixes, so will not be *merged*.)

The Apache documentation linked to in the question refers to Apache 2.4. On Apache 2.4 `Indexes` are not enabled by default (*default:* `Options FollowSymLinks`), so for this to be enabled on the server at all it must be explicitly defined *somewhere*.

On Apache 2.2 `Indexes` are enabled by default (*default:* `Options All`), but this *can be overridden* in the VirtualHost container (providing it is not defined elsewhere).

Comment: Ah. Now that makes much more sense. In Ubuntu 16.04, they have `Options Indexes, FollowSymLinks` as the default of `/var/www/` defined in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`... so a very strong default for the entire `/var/www/` folder found in the main configuration file!

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem in the past. Based on the help documentation strictly speaking the `options -indexes` directive should work in the main vhost block but in my experience and based on all examples available on how to use this directive when dealing with disabling directory indexing the directive has to be within the `<Directory ""></Directory>` block in the vhost file.